# Storing normal password(not encrypted) but login fails - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, passwords, laravel-5.4

I'm storing normal password without encryption but it doesn't find matches at the time of login.

Here is my **LoginController**

```
public function login(){
    $email = Input::get('email');
    $password = Input::get('password');

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password]))
    {
        echo "Login Successful";
    }else{
        echo "Failed!";
    }
}
```

Any idea how to fix?

Note: Please don't tell me to use encryption, I'm not going to deliver this to any client or anyone.

Comment: you cant no use encryption if you are using the default attempt method... so you either use it or write your own login,

Comment: If I use my own login, can I use Auth::check() functionality? @jycr753

Comment: a dirty hack would be to use normal eloquent to compare username and password, and when you get the user create the seassion with`§Auth:: login($user);`

Comment: You should still use encryption, it's there by default, why wouldn't you want to, just works out of the box! At this point, it's more trouble removing it than use using it, even if it's only for you.

Comment: please dont store plain passwords, its a very bad practice. I will never register to a site knowing it store plain password.

Answer (score 4):

Under the hood `attempt()` method uses [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) to check entered password:

```
password_verify($value, $hashedValue);
```

So, if you want to store not encrypted password for some crazy reason, you'll need to create your own auth system. But I'd really recommend you to forget about this and use standard Laravel auth system with encrypted passwords.